# integral domain as an intersection of localizations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am stuck on trying to prove that
$$\bigcap_{m \text{ maximal}}A_m = A$$ 
where $A$ is an integral domain (commutative, ring with unity).
I would appreciate any hint! Thanks!

Comment: oops yes. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If fraction $\rm\:f\not\in A\:$ then its  *denominator ideal* $\rm\: I = \{ d\in A \mid  d\:\!f\in A\} \ne (1),\:$ so $\rm\!\: I\!\:$ is contained in a maximal ideal $\rm\:M,\:$ so $\rm\:f\not\in A_M,\:$ thus $\rm\:f\:$ is not in the intersection. The converse is clear.